# Set spacing in a selectBox

Tags: libgdx

The wiki says that I can set the spacing between Items in a selectBox.
However, I could not find such method either in SelectBoxStyl or ScrollPaneStyle or ListStyle.... and it looks awful on small smart-phones...

I am testing this sample code from [their official repository](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/UITest.java)

```
    final SelectBox dropdown = new SelectBox(skin);
    dropdown.setItems("Android1", "Windows1", "Linux1");
    dropdown.setSelected("Linux6");
```

Any idea? Is there another way to display a selectBox in friendlier way on mobile devices?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @www139 It is JAVA...the language used by the Framework LIBGDX

Comment: ok. Sorry can't help :( I don't know java well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spacing is determined by the `topHeight` and `bottomHeight` parameters of the Drawable that's set as the `selection` parameter in the ListStyle that is set as the `listStyle` parameter of the SelectBoxStyle.

This is probably most easily done with a NinePatchDrawable, which has built-in support for top height and bottom height.

You can otherwise call `setTopHeight()` and `setBottomHeight()` on the Drawable that you use in the style, but you may need to mess around with tweaking a height value as well with `setHeight()` to get it to draw correctly, or subclass the type of Drawable you're using and override the `draw()` method to correctly account for your desired `topHeight` and `bottomHeight`.